# Filebeat regex - whitespace before digits

Tags: regex, filebeat

I have the following config in my `filebeat.yml` :

```
- type: log
  close_renamed: true
  paths:
    - /logs/example.log
  multiline:
    pattern: '^[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}'
    negate: true
    match: after
    timeout: 3s
  fields_under_root: true
  fields:
    type: oracle
    sourcetype: oracle
  tags: ["oracle"]
```

Example.log (truncated) :

```
...
Thu Oct  1 23:01:00 2020 +00:00
LENGTH : '275'
ACTION :[7] 'CONNECT'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[9] 'test_user'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1762369616'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[21] 'testdevserver'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[3] '100'

Thu Oct  1 23:01:00 2020 +00:00
LENGTH : '296'
ACTION :[29] 'SELECT STATUS FROM V$INSTANCE'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[9] 'test_user'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1762369616'
SESSIONID:[10] '4294967295'
USERHOST:[21] 'testdevserver'
CLIENT ADDRESS:[0] ''
ACTION NUMBER:[1] '3'
```

I noticed that this pattern `'^[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}'` doesnt work for the example above `Thu Oct  1 23:01:00 2020 +00:00` because there is a whitespace after `Oct` and before `1`.
How do I remove this whitespace so the pattern would match accordingly?

Thanks!
J

Comment: You can repeat matching the space using a quantifier `+` but as it can be `Oct  1` you could also update the quantifier for the digit to `\d{1,2}` see https://regex101.com/r/RKUq3O/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple spaces instead of a single space, you can use `+` to match 1 or more.

Currently that would not get the desired match, as the day starts with a single digit 1. You can update the day part to match 1 or 2 digits using `\d{1,2}`

```
^[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} +[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKUq3O/1)

You might for example make the pattern a bit more precise for the time and year part. You could extend it to also make the days and months an exact match.

```
^[A-Za-z]{3} +[A-Za-z]{3} +(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) +(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d +(?:19|20)\d{2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WCsT9Z/1)

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate your help :)